# What's the consequence of the sacrifice dedicated to Shadow?

Tags: neil-gaiman, american-gods

By sacrificing the death into Shadow's name, it seems that Laura created a significant precedent.

What's the consequence of the sacrifice dedicated to Shadow?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is entirely clear.  I'm also not sure if I should use spoiler tags here, so I will play it safe.

Shadow

> is Baldur, a god and son of a god.  It's possible the sacrifice empowers him somewhat, though Baldur is not a god of war per se.  Recall that after the battle, and after he takes the coin back from Laura, he runs into Sam Back Crow.  She is with a girlfriend.  He slips some flowers into her hands but neither Sam Black Crow or the other girl see Shadow.  So he's "behind the scenery" as it were.  Perhaps that was partly a result of the sacrifice, though this is highly speculative.

Comment: i'm not sure you should be definitely saying that Shadow was who you say he was.  There are plenty of arguments that he is not.